# How do I enable language without importing translations?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I need to enable many languages on a site. I don't want Drupal downloads translations, since only few forms and pages will be actually translated on the front-end so I'll handle that manually.

Is there a way to avoid translations are downloaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drush cset locale.settings translation.import_enabled 0` or any other method to disable that flag should do the trick.